# Is it possible to use airdrop on iphone4?

Tags: ios, airdrop

I have ipad mini and iphone 4 and i want to transfer some music from ipad to iphone. Is it possible to use Airdrop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the hardware radio doesn't work in the manner needed for AirDrop to function.

See the fine print of http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/#airdrop which states:

### AirDrop is available on iPhone 5 or later, iPad (4th generation), iPad mini, and iPod touch (5th generation) and requires an iCloud account

Comment: does Airdrop use wifi or Bluetooth? even in the case if it works with Bluetooth?

Comment: It is WiFi file exchange using an ad-hoc, non router based 802.11 protocol. Think of it as a mesh network that doesn't care whether any of the devices are connected to any or the same WiFI network. I believe bluetooth is only used to negotiate the wireless connection and not transfer files, but I don't have a reference or any facts behind that belief.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use Airdrop with an iPhone 4: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5887

While your iPad mini supports AirDrop, the your iPhone 4 does not - and as far as I'm aware, music can't be transferred via AirDrop.

That said, for $25/year, you can turn on [iTunes Match](http://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/), which will put a copy of your iTunes library in iCloud, allowing you to access your music anywhere. You can also transfer the music by using a Mac.

Comment: Good answer on iTunes Match. It's less flexible than if you could "beam" a song to another device without being connected to the internet, but it is available today and works quite well for many people's needs.